# ASP.NET MVC C#/Javascript Website, Open File on local client drive when clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, network-drive

This is all happening on a LAN, all clients have a mounted drive called media_share with drive letter M. When a client accesses the LAN IIS server, they are presented with a web page that shows all the files on that M drive. I want to make it so that when they click on a DIV (representing the file) it automatically opens it locally. Although the IIS server will be able to view the data on the M drive, it cannot serve up the data to the user; this is because it will be too slow, the M drive is a SAN. I presume Javascript would be the approach, but that presents significant security roadblocks since it doesn't allow the browser to run arbitrary commands. I'm beginning to think this is going to have to be a desktop application to make it work, but I've already written a lot of web code.

Comment: The file is in a network location or client's computer ?

Comment: The file would be on a network location, that the client computer can access via the mounted drive letter M.

Comment: Well you know the user, so if IIS has access to the SAN, you could logically get the list of files. Then you could have some kind of console app running locally on their machine which is waiting for a command to open a file. But this architecture seems very iffy. I'd opt for a local app over all that.

Comment: Yeah I'm getting the list of files fine now and showing them to the user in the website, now I was trying to implement that open operation on click. I did consider having a service running locally, but how would the browser click event even tell the local service to open that file... maybe via a local database but that's a silly option. Perhaps via an XML that the browser downloads and that the service is monitoring but that also seems silly. God, do I have to switch to a desktop application?

Comment: Off the top of my head the service could be watching a database, running a query every few seconds to make sure nothing needs to be open. But I'm guessing there's a better way, somehow keeping the connection open and being alerted when a file needs to be opened, I just can't think of the right technology stack to do it. Maybe MSMQ.